# Determine which statement is grammatically correct

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

I don't know how to choose between *which* and *who* in these phrases.

Which of these phrases is grammatically correct?

> Tom Smith, **which** is John Smith’s brother

> Tom Smith, **who** is John Smith’s brother

Comment: Hello Michael and welcome to ELL. On this site, we ask questions about aspects of the English language. We don't allow questions asking which is correct. It looks like you're asking about the choice of relative pronouns, so I've edited your question for you. If I'm wrong, please [edit] it yourself and tell us what aspect of English you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms, 'who' is for people, 'which' is for things.

Think of Doctor Who - you couldn't imagine him being called Doctor Which;)